# Custom Container View Controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I am using the containment API to create a custom container view controller

Creation of Parent View Controller in ViewDidLoad of Parent, and Setting of Child View Controllers:

```
[self addChildViewController:newA];
[self addChildViewController:newB];
[self addChildViewController:newC];
```

Now once these childVC have been added I can transition using:

```
[self transitionFromViewController:from
                  toViewController:to
                          duration:1.0
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                        animations:nil
                        completion:^(BOOL b){
                            [to didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                            [from.view removeFromSuperview];
                            [from removeFromParentViewController];
                        }];
```

My question now is must I **remove** the current childVC from the parentVC to show the new VC?

```
                        completion:^(BOOL b){
                            [to didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                            [from.view removeFromSuperview];
                            [from removeFromParentViewController];
                        }
```

Is there a way that I can preserve those childVCs' and simply do swipe/button-action to then navigate between these childVCs'?

Comment: I know you have now mastered custom container view controllers, but just for clarity on this old question, don't forget to call `[newA didMoveToParentViewController:self]`, once for each `addChildViewController`. When you add, call `didMove...` when done (not just at transition). When you remove, call `willMove...:nil` before you do it. See [adding and removing a child](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW13)

Comment: The calling of `didMoveToParentViewController` and `willMoveToParentViewController` is a function of when you do `addChildViewController` and `removeFromParentViewController`, _not_ when you're doing the `transitionFromViewController`.

Comment: Once again thanks for the incredible amount of help...you have gone out of your way to help me on a number of occasions this weekend....so based on what you have said I am missing `willMove...:nil` in the `completion` block?

Comment: You generally do `willMove...:nil` _before_ you even try to remove a child, must less the animation of that removal. See code listing 14-3 in [Adding and Removing a Child](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW13). You will, though, do the `didMove...` of the newly added child in the completion block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you don't need to remove the `from` view controller's view from the view hierarchy manually. This method handles that for you upon completion of your animation block. From the docs on this method:

> This method adds the second view controller’s view to the view
>   hierarchy and then performs the animations defined in your animations
>   block. After the animation completes, it removes the first view
>   controller’s view from the view hierarchy.

As a caveat to this, though, the animation block cannot be `NULL` as it is in your code example (that being said, you have `nil`, not `NULL`, which doesn't make sense since the `animations` parameter is a block, not an Objective-C object).

**UPDATE:** Depending on your implementation, `viewDidLoad` may get called repeatedly if the memory for that view is cleaned up. A `UITabBarController`, for instance, generally only calls viewDidLoad upon adding your VC's to the tab bar, and just calls viewWill/DidAppear after that. Similarly, a `UINavigationController` won't call `viewDidLoad` when you pop to a view controller because it's been maintaining it in its navigation stack, but will call `viewDidLoad` if you pop off of a VC and then push it back on (usually). If you're not getting the behavior you want, you can subclass this method in your container implementation.

** **NOTE** I am removing the iphone-sdk-4.0 tag from your question, as the containment API did not become available until 5.0

Comment: I should have written that better ( I will edit) I am not necessarily concerned with removing...my question more revolves around is it necessary to remove it at all, can I maintain in memory so I can  transition without having to load over and over

Comment: So as I said, this method will automatically handle removing the first view from the super view upon animation completion. See my edit for more detail.